# Mod rewrite from bigcartel links to shopify products

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to rewrite URLs from `/product/PRODUCT_LINK` to `/products/PRODUCT_LINK`.  How would I put this into a .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to simply redirect, then you can use either mod_alias:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/product/(.+)$ /products/$1
```

or mod_rewrite (which is preferred if you already have rewrite rules):

```
RewriteRule ^product/(.+)$ /products/$1 [L,R=301]
```